# How to convert owl to uml in Protege?

Tags: uml, owl, protege

I am using protege 5 version,

How do I translate owl to uml ?,

Is there a uml diagram library for protege 5.x ?

Answer (score 4):

This is an area that has interested me for some time. To the best of my knowledge there is no current tool to achieve this. There is a plugin for Protege4. See [OWL2UML](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OWL2UML) and [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b716/75fe9b71e3251054e0e7db20c686184513a6.pdf). Another problem is that the plugin may only support an old version or subset of XMI.

If possible it may make sense to rather use Protege4. Or, if possible, you could attempt to do the translation by hand. You can find more on the OWL<-->UML translation on my [website](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/).

Comment: Firstly, thank you but,I installed protege4, I added the library but the owl2uml screen does not open.